# How to load 10,000 users to salesforce

Tags: permissions, licenses

We have heavy custom development salesforce app, we have a customer with 10,000 licenses, just to make sure no hiccups to the system with these many users we are planning to do performance testing.

I would like to know

1. What are the steps/or how can we load 10,000 users to salesforce org?
2. What kind of permissions or salesforce editions needed to test?
3. Any recommended open source test tools?

Comment: You would need to use a sandbox from that client as otherwise you won't have any feasible environment for that many licences. Secondly to actually performance test you would want to use a client's full copy environment as that will have the actual data volumes as well as numbers of users.

Comment: You should not do a performance test without informing salesforce support.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230841&type=1

They monitor your org for implicit limits that are not visible under any setup menus

Comment: There is some odd, even suspicious about this question: why would someone with no idea how to load a single user, be responsible for loading 10k users for a very large client...

Comment: @Robs
Worked with few big consultancies, I have actually seen this happen.  :(

Comment: @Robs... where did I mention I will be loading 10k users & also I mentioned performance testing... I can do it in my org as well... We never had customers with that many licenses so planning to do performance testing... I am a QA Engineer working for a product based company, I am planning some test strategy around that...

Comment: @PranayJaiswal....Translate all Judgements into Empathy because When we judge others we contribute to violence....courtesy ..Marshall Rosenberg's

Comment: @ChandraBoyapati the title of your question has 10,000 users in it...

Answer (score 8):

Loading 10,000 users is the same as loading 1 user. Just map the fields appropriately and upload the records via Data Loader/API/etc. To answer your questions:

> What are the steps/or how can we load 10,000 users to salesforce org?

Install Apex Data Loader, create CSV file, upload users to target org.

> What kind of permissions or salesforce editions needed to test?

Manage Users and Modify All Data (e.g. a System Administrator), and any Salesforce Edition that has API access (e.g. Enterprise or higher).

> Any recommended open source test tools?

There's literally no reason to test this. Salesforce is more than capable of creating 10,000 users, and it's no more challenging than creating a single user.

If you can successfully upload one record, you can successfully upload 10,000 records. You're not going to find a "test" environment that has 10,000 licenses available, short of using one of the client's sandboxes. Even then, you're really wasting your time.

Again, loading 10,000 users is exactly as difficult as loading 1 user. You simply need to make sure that all your data is in order.

Answer (score 5):

> What are the steps/or how can we load 10,000 users to salesforce org?

You can install dataloader and prepare csv file and upload the csv.

To upload user record it is good to capture following information

- USERNAME - It should be unique across all salesforce orgs.
- LASTNAME - Mandatory
- FIRSTNAME
- ALIAS - Mandatory, It should be max 8 digit
- COMPANYNAME
- DEPARTMENT
- EMAIL - Mandatory
- ISACTIVE
- TIMEZONESIDKEY
- USERROLEID
- LOCALESIDKEY
- EMAILENCODINGKEY
- PROFILEID - Mandatory
- USERTYPE - It is Salesforce if you are using `Salesforce` license.
- LANGUAGELOCALEKEY
- External_Id__C - If you are taking user extract from external system then capture a reference of the Id.

Following points to be noted:

1. Before uploading, you need to capture `ProfileId` (which is mandatory) and `USERROLEID` (which is optional, though you can map).
2. If your org doesn't have 10000 or required licenses then better you can mark user as `ISACTIVE=false` during upload.
3. If you assign role during user upload using `USERROLEID` then upload will be much slower due to Salesforce internal sharing and other calculations.
4. After first upload you can update ManagerId respective to users.
5. Salesforce doesn't send emails to those users for password reset during upload. So, Administrator need to update those users manually, selecting the checkbox for sending password. So, you need to plan accordingly for this update.
6. By the way, inactive user cannot be assigned to a queue, through inactive user can be a record owner.

So, preparing a user data will take significant time considering all the above points.

Rest of the answers, you can refer @sfdcfox's answer